# wrong colour assignment

Tags: r, ggplot2

I realized that ggplot assigns the colours to the vertical lines in a different way than I expect it to do.

Creating the data frame:

```
wages <- rnorm(100, 0.9, 0.5)
ids <- as.factor(round(rnorm(100, 1342, 98)))
x <- data.frame(ids, wages)
```

Drawing the distribution, specifying colours of the vertical lines:

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = wages)) +
  geom_density(alpha=.4, colour = "darkgrey", fill = "darkgrey") +
  geom_vline(data = x, aes(xintercept = mean(x$wages), colour = "green"),
             linetype = 1, size = 0.5)+
  geom_vline(data = x, aes(xintercept = median(x$wages), colour = "blue"),
             linetype = 1, size = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(data = x, aes(xintercept = mean(x$wages)+1*sd(x$wages), colour = "red"),
             linetype = 1, size = 0.5)+
  xlim(c(0,3))
```

[image: enter code here]

Your graph will look differently, however one result stays the same: The median and the mean+1sd line colours are switched. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: `colour=` should be placed outside the `aes()` if it is not mapped to variable.

Comment: @DidzisElferts could you add that as an answer?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra This question in others forms has been asked allready, just didn't have time to find duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are providing colors by their name and not mapping to variable, `colour=` should be placed outside the `aes()`.

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = wages)) +
  geom_density(alpha=.4, colour = "darkgrey", fill = "darkgrey") +
  geom_vline(data = x, aes(xintercept = mean(x$wages)),colour = "green",
             linetype = 1, size = 0.5)+
  geom_vline(data = x, aes(xintercept = median(x$wages)),colour = "blue",
             linetype = 1, size = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(data = x, aes(xintercept = mean(x$wages)+1*sd(x$wages)),colour = "red",
             linetype = 1, size = 0.5)+
  xlim(c(0,3))
```

Comment: Thanks again for your solution. I did some research on the existence of a duplicate question, however I couldn't find any.